# Couldn't match expected type 'Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString' with actual type '[Char]'

Tags: haskell, aeson

I'm trying to get a simple Json parser up and running in my Haskell code, I came across Data.Aeson which seemed like a viable solution to my problem

I followed the [example code on the page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.6.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html), and with some minor modifications, here's what I got:

```
{-#LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Text
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad

data Person = 
    Person { firstName :: Text
           , lastName  :: Text
           , age       :: Int
           } deriving Show

instance FromJSON Person where
    parseJSON (Object v) =
        Person <$> v .: "f_name"
               <*> v .: "l_name"
               <*> v .: "age"
    parseJSON _ = mzero
```

Running the following in GHCi causes the nasty message in the title to appear:

```
decode "{\"f_name\":\"Haskell\", \"l_name\":\"Curry\",\"age\":114}" :: Maybe Person
```

So, does anyone here have an idea what went wrong? I followed the example code almost exactly as it was written, so why is it that it fails?

Comment: `decode` is expecting a `ByteString` and you've given a normal string literal (type of `[Char]`). Look at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring

Comment: the example I followed used a normal string... You would assume the example on hackage.haskell.org is written correctly...

Comment: You probably need to do `:set -XOverloadedStrings` in GHCi before calling `decode`.

Comment: yeah that did it... can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Before calling `decode` in ghci, you need to do `:set -XOverloadedStrings`, so the string literal is treated as a ByteString instead of a String. The pragma in the module only applies to the code in the module, not to what you do in ghci.